# Display 10^n as power

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, display

How can I tell MMA to display input of the form `10^n` as $10^n$ and not e.g. as 1000 for $n = 3$ or the rational $\frac{1}{1000}$ for $n = -3$.

This would help to keep tables compact when some parameters sweep across a large range of magnitudes, e.g.

```
TableForm[Table[x y, {x, Table[10^n, {n, -3, 3}]}, {y, Table[10^n, {n, -3, 3}]}], 
 TableHeadings -> {Table[10^n, {n, -3, 3}], Table[10^n, {n, -3, 3}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: A nice extension to this question would be to have a way to display exact integer (or rational) multiple of 10^n, such as 12000000, represented by 12 10^6

Comment: @andre If you don't mind the trailing dot on the mantissa, you can do `EngineeringForm@N[12000000]` to get `12.*10^6` (or `ScientificForm@N[12000000]` for `1.2*10^7`)... but I do mind.

Comment: I do mind too, because I want to recognise exact values from approximative values.

Comment: Another possibility for your table would be to use logarithms.

Comment: @ivbc You mean as in [Alexei's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148797/42227)?

Comment: Not exactly. You could define new variables xlog=log[x] and ylog=log[y]. If your logs are base 10 and you have a lot of powers of 10 it should look good. Not sure if it conveis what you want though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An alternative would be to define your own number form:

```
ClearAll[form]
SetAttributes[form, Listable]

form[x_] := ScientificForm[N@x, NumberFormat -> (Superscript[10, #3] &)]
form[1] := Superscript[10, 0]

10^Partition[Range[-6, 6], 7, 1] // form // 
   TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {#[[4]], #[[4]]}] &
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution. Unlike the other answers where the scope is obvious, however, defining a custom number format might lead someone who did not write the code himself to expect that `form` works with all numbers. Instead, it ignores the mantissa (including sign) and acts like a floor function to the exponent, e.g. `form[999] = 10^2` or `form[-3456] = 10^3`. Also, `form[10^-\[Infinity]] = 10` but that could be fixed by `form[10^-\[Infinity]] := 0`. Still, this could lead to trouble when used carelessly.

Comment: hey @eldo, I came up with a very similar answer before seeing yours. I am not sure if i should edit yours or post mine as a new one, or something else... I posted for now so that someone can tell me what to do.

Answer (score 7):

I hadnt seen Eldos answer before now, but I did copy the `SetAttributes` and `ClearAll` from him.

Define:

```
ClearAll[newForm]
SetAttributes[newForm, Listable]

newForm[x_] :=
  If[IntegerQ@x == True && Divisible[x, 10],
   ScientificForm[x // N,
    NumberFormat -> (
      If[Length@Characters@#3 != 0,
        If[ToExpression@#1 == 1,
         Row[{Superscript[10, 
            ToString[ToExpression@#3 - Length@Characters@#1 + 2]]}],
         Row[{x/10^(ToExpression@#3 - Length@Characters@#1 + 2), 
           "\[Times]", 
           Superscript[10, 
            ToString[ToExpression@#3 - Length@Characters@#1 + 2]]}]],
        #1] &)],
   ScientificForm[x]];
```

So the following comand gives a nice result

```
v = {1, 8^5, 130, 130., 15400000, 11.^7, 10^3};
newForm[v]
```

[image]

Comment: OP wanted 10^3 without an integer multiplying it. Your answer gives 1 x 10^3.

Comment: Does it? O hadn't tested for this case, thanks for letting me know. I will find a solution latter.

Comment: @JackLaVigne, error corrected!

Comment: You got my vote

Answer (score 6):

```
TableForm[
 Table[
  Superscript[10, x + y],
  {x, -3, 3},
  {y, -3, 3}
  ], TableHeadings -> {
   Table[Superscript[10, n], {n, -3, 3}],
   Table[Superscript[10, n], {n, -3, 3}]}
 ]
```

[image: table]

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
  TableForm[
 Table[10^ToString[Log[10, x y]], {x, Table[10^n, {n, -3, 3}]}, {y, 
   Table[10^n, {n, -3, 3}]}], 
 TableHeadings -> {Table[10^ToString[n], {n, -3, 3}], 
   Table[10^ToString[n], {n, -3, 3}]}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 6):

```
a = Range[-3, 3];
```

HoldForm:

```
TableForm[Replace[Outer[Plus, a, a], x_ :> 10 ^ HoldForm @ x, {2}], 
    TableHeadings -> Replace[{a, a}, x_ :> 10 ^ HoldForm @ x, {2}] ]
```

[image]

Get back to initial form, if needed:

```
% // ReleaseHold
```

Answer (score 4):

An example using `Format`:

```
Format[h[x_]] := 
 With[{p = Log10[x]}, 
  If[p == 0, Style[1, 20], Style[10^HoldForm[p], 20]]]
r = PowerRange[1/1000, 1000, 10];
tu = Tuples[r, 2];
TableForm[Partition[h@*Times @@@ tu, 7], 
 TableHeadings -> Map[h, {r, r}, {2}], TableAlignments -> Center]
```

[image]