# How do we make HoldForm reads from external list?

Tags: formatting

```
In[716]:= Block[{d = 10^6}, HoldForm[ # A] & /@ d]

Out[716]= 1000000
```

I would like to get this

```
In[715]:= HoldForm[ 10^6 A]
Out[715]= 10^6 A
```

**Update**
T make it clear, I have a list with the form `d=`{$10^{4},10^{5},10^{6}$}, I would like to use d in the code and print the exact form of `d`. minimal example

```
Block[{d = 10^3}, 
 LogLinearPlot[d r, {r, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 90}}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style[HoldForm[L = # A] &[d], Red], 
     Scaled[{.5, 1.2}]]}]]
```

[image]

However, if put $10^{3}$ inside `HoldForm` it gives the desired results.

```
Block[{d = 10^3}, 
 LogLinearPlot[d r, {r, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 90}}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style[HoldForm[L = 10^3 A], Red], 
     Scaled[{.5, 1.2}]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I have to go. I hope someone can answer you on the updates. Will remove my answer. But if all what you want is just to format numbers as `10^n` you can use `ScientificForm` for this instead of this HoldForm business. see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148794/display-10n-as-power as example.

Comment: @Nasser, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use `HoldForm` in the definition of `d` and release as required.

```
Block[{d = HoldForm[10^3]}, 
 LogLinearPlot[ReleaseHold@d r, {r, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> All,
  Frame -> True,
  PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["L = `` A\n", d], Red]]]
```

[image]